# Using filepath for FileInputStream throws java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, serialization, java-io, eofexception

I'm trying to import a file into my class via FileInputStream, but it throws the error

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Homepage.start(Homepage.java:50)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't really know why the source is unknown, as the file does exist on my computer.

So basically, the file is imported from the filepath that it is stored in. I'm not sure if you can set filepaths for a FileInputStream, but I think my code should technically check out.

```java
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Homepage extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String file = null;
        String file2 = null;
        String file3 = null;
        String file4 = null;
        String file5 = null;
        String file6 = null;
        String file7 = null;
        String file8 = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxthe\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyDesktop\\apps.bin");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            file = (String) in.readObject();
            file2 = (String) in.readObject();
            file3 = (String) in.readObject();
            file4 = (String) in.readObject();
            file5 = (String) in.readObject();
            file6 = (String) in.readObject();
            file7 = (String) in.readObject();
            file8 = (String) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }
            catch (IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                System.out.println("Class not found!");
                c.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
```

More background info:

The objects file1 -> file8 are serialized filepaths chosen in a FileChooser from another application. Didn't think that would be necessary info, but if anyone is wondering why those objects exist, there is your answer.

Anyways, if anyone could help me get this sorted out, that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Edit: Current Code

(here is the EOF error on the deserialization)

```java
public class Homepage extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String file = null;
        String file2 = null;
        String file3 = null;
        String file4 = null;
        String file5 = null;
        String file6 = null;
        String file7 = null;
        String file8 = null;
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\xxthe\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyDesktop\\apps.bin";
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            file = (String) in.readObject();
            file2 = (String) in.readObject(); 
            file3 = (String) in.readObject();
            file4 = (String) in.readObject();
            file5 = (String) in.readObject();
            file6 = (String) in.readObject();
            file7 = (String) in.readObject();
            file8 = (String) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        }
            catch (IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                System.out.println("Class not found!");
                c.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
This is from the first class, where the serialization to file "apps.bin" occurs.
try {
                String fileName = "src/doc/apps.bin";
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                os.writeObject(application_1);
                os.writeObject(application_2);
                os.writeObject(application_3);
                os.writeObject(application_4);
                os.writeObject(application_5);
                os.writeObject(application_6);
                os.writeObject(application_7);
                os.writeObject(application_8);
                os.close();
                System.out.println("Selected app filepaths saved to src/doc/apps.bin!");
            } catch(FileNotFoundException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace(); 
            }

            File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\xxthe\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyDesktop");
            File fileExport = new File("src/doc/apps.bin");
            String fileExportName = fileExport.getName();

            folder.mkdirs();
            File fileExportRun = new File("C:\\Users\\xxthe\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyDesktop\\" + fileExportName);
```

Comment: The exception occurs on line `50` of your code which, from throwing your code into an editor, is `ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);`. Something must be wrong with the contents of your file. Can you show the code that creates the file?

Comment: @Slaw Sure thing, check the original post, just added the extra code.

Comment: You don't appear to serialize anything to the file (unless you simply omitted that part of the code). The `EOF` in `EOFException` stands for "end-of-file". An `ObjectInputStream` expects the stream to have a certain format and it's probably looking for some header during initialization. Since you don't serialize anything to the file it reaches the end before it finds the header—thus the `EOFException`.

Comment: That's odd, I serialized 8 strings to the file.
Check again for edit @Slaw

Comment: The file is *empty.* That is the meaning of the exception. It could have something to do with your redundant existence-checking and `createNewFile()` calls, which accomplish nothing useful and only add overhead. And possibly introduce bugs like this. Especially as you appear to be doing all that *after* serializing data to the file, which is even more pointless if there is such a thing. Remove all calls to `exists()` and `createNewFile()` and retest.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: @user207421 I removed the ```createNewFile()``` and ```exists()``` calls, still gives the EOF exception. 

The weird part is that when I open the file "apps.bin" located in the project folder, the data is displayed there. Now I just want to save the file "apps.bin" to the directory where I can pull it from there to be used in another app.

Comment: So the file is still empty. Please post the current code. If you want to rename a file, use the method provided for the purpose, and `File.createNewFile()` isn't it.

Comment: Check original post again for updated code - everything before the serialization is irrelevant to the issue. @user207421

Comment: From the code you posted, nothing is written to the file you are trying to read from, hence it is empty, which causes the EOF exception.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I fixed the issue by creating the filepath by itself instead of using the apps.bin file in the project. Everything works as intended! 

Sorry for the small issue. Thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: Was going to suggest you may be writing to a different file than the one you read from. Was that the problem?

Comment: Yeah, @Slaw. Got it all figured out and it works nicely. Thanks for the help